# How to create new product slider in home page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.2, home-page, slider

I want to create a new **product slider** in **home page** of my website **without using external extension**.

Comment: please try below urls : 
https://magenticians.com/magento-2-display-products-on-homepage/
https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/magento-2-how-insert-products-homepage.html

Comment: Paid one, but worked pretty well for me - https://nwdthemes.com/magento-2-extensions/magento-2-product-slider/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Display Products on Homepage in Magento 2

Another way to make the homepage attractive, though, is to show the best products on the homepage of your store. It is the best way to get the attention of the users towards your products which increases the chances of more sales.

So, today you are going to learn how to display products on the homepage of Magento 2. In this tutorial, I will show you two types of products list on the homepage:

- Products from Specific Category.
- New Added Products.

Products from Specific Category
Go to the Admin panel of your store and navigate to CONTENT → Pages.

[image]

Now click on Edit from the Select dropdown of the homepage.

[image]

Unfold the Content section and then click on Insert Widget from the homepage editor.

[image]

Now select Catalog Products List from Widget Type dropdown and fill all the details according to your requirements. After providing all the details, go to Conditions attribute, select the Category option, and just select the category of your choice that you want to show. At last, click on Insert Widget.

[image]

Now just click on Save Page.

[image]

Now go to the homepage of your store, and you will see the products from a specific category on the homepage of your Magento 2.

[image]

New Added Products
Click on insert widget from the Content editor of your homepage.

[image]

Select Catalog New Products List from Widget Type Dropdown and fill the details according to your requirements. After providing all the details, click on the Insert Widget.

[image]

Now click on Save Page.

[image]

Go to the homepage of your store, and you will see the recently added products on the homepage of your Magento 2.

[image]

Showing products on the homepage of a store is one of the best approaches to boost sales and now you should be able to show products on the homepage of Magento 2. In this Magento 2 homepage customization series, you learned how to add image slider in Magento 2 and how to display products on the homepage of Magento 2.

> Reference:
> https://magenticians.com/magento-2-display-products-on-homepage/

**I hope this will help**

Comment: Please don't  copy all content from a source and pasted it here

Comment: @AmitBera I would want to share the link because if url is inactive then it goes to 404 error. So solution must be long lasting so it also help others

Comment: @AmitBera if you still think it is unfair I will delete my answer. It's detail oriented so no more detail is needed. I know you are moderator if you want I will delete my answer. You can see that's why I share reference link

Comment: @Muhammad Hasham , it is just a message to you as copy same content from another source, will create an issue at google search. Hope you will understand my  point.

Comment: your refer link is opening at here. I  donot see 404 page.

Comment: Thanks @AmitBera I will surely take care of this in future. Once again thanks for notifying me

Comment: @AmitBera It is opening now but in future if url is inactive then there is problem answer is not relevant

Comment: how can we make it in a slider way ?

Answer (score 1):

The **homepage** can be considered as the most important part of every website. Customers will see your homepage first before they decide to shop, so your job is to make the homepage really appealing to the customer. If not, they will leave your site immediately.  One of the best ways to attract users is to **insert products on your homepage.** Because when they visit your website, they see [the products](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/6-types-product-types-magento-2.html) that attract them more, from that they are an incentive for customers to buy the products. You also can insert manufacturers/brands on the home page, read [this guide](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-shop-by-brand/show-brand-on-home-page.html).

**Tips:** Use [Mageplaza Product Slider (Free)](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-product-slider-extension/) to add Featured products, best-selling products to Homepage or anywhere.

In this article, we will show **how to insert products on the homepage** with only some simple steps.

### To insert products on the homepage in Magento 2, follow 5 steps:

- Step 1: Navigate to Content > Page
- Step 2: Select Edit under Actions menu
- Step 3: Choose Catalog Products List option
- Step 4: Select Category and click on Insert widget button
- Step 5: Click on Save page to finish

#### Step 1: Navigate to Content > Page

First, you need to have [Magento 2 admin panel](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-security/) on your store. Navigate to `Content` > `Pages`

[image: How to Insert Products on Homepage]

Here the pages will display and you will see all of your store’s pages.

[image: How to Insert Products on Homepage in Magento 2]

#### Step 2: Select Edit under Actions menu

On `Homepage` title, from the `Select` drop down, select `Edit` drop down under `Actions` menu.

[image: Magento 2 Insert Products on Homepage]

Now go to the `Content` section and click on `Insert widget`

[image: How to Insert Products on Homepage]

#### Step 3: Choose Catalog Products List option

`Insert Widget` page will appear, select the `Catalog Products List` option for the `Widget type`. Mageplaza can help you list featured products, bestsellers, new arrivals, daily deals on the homepage easily, [see how](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-automatic-related-products/?utm_source=kbs).

[image: How to Insert Products on Homepage Magento 2]

#### Step 4: Select Category and click on the Insert Widget button

On the next page,  there is a `Conditions` attribute, select `Category` from the options and choose the `category` you want to show on the homepage of your store. Then, click on `Insert Widget`.

[image: Magento 2 Insert Products on Homepage]

#### Step 5: Click on Save page to finish

Come back to the `Content` tab, you will see an icon for `Products` in the text box. Click on the `Save Page` button to complete the changing of the page.

[image: How to Insert Products on Homepage in Magento 2]

### To summarize

To do all steps is so easy. Now, it's time to **insert new products on homepage** which helps attract your customers as well as increase the traffics and boost sales for your Magento 2 store.

**Tips:** Use [Mageplaza Product Slider (Free)](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-product-slider-extension/) to add Featured products, best-selling products to Homepage or anywhere.